# Filtering Pandas dataset based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using this dataframe:

```
  Callsign  Distance    AirportSize
0   HVN19   3.727263    2
1   HVN19   3.727263    1
2   HVN19   11.485452   2
3   CCA839  2.094717    2
4   CCA839  2.094717    1
5   CCA839  6.622537    2
6   CES219  1.751279    1
7   CES219  5.436940    4
8   CES219  6.950773    4
9   ETH704  2.976954    4
10  ETH704  3.844980    4
11  ETH704  5.452634    4
```

I'm trying to connect **Callsign** with the smallest value of **AirportSize** only if **Distance** between airports for the same **Callsign** is less than 1. Besides, I would like to keep only these lines and drop other rows within the same **Callsign**.

I will give an example of the first three lines within the same **Callsign** (*HVN19*) to be more clear: we can instantly drop the 3rd row because of **Distance** difference between the third row and first two lines (11.485452 - 3.727263 > 1). When it comes to the remaining two rows, we choose the second row because **AirportSize** is smaller compared to the first row (1 < 2).

The result should look like this:

```
  Callsign  Distance    AirportSize

1   HVN19   3.727263    1
2   CCA839  2.094717    1
3   CES219  1.751279    1
4   ETH704  2.976954    4
```

Comment: why is `CES219  1.751279    1` in your expected output

Comment: That line has the smallest distance compared to the other two lines below (1.751279 compared to 5.436940 and 6.950773). The overall goal is to have the line with the smallest distance, but if the distances between the consecutive rows within the same **Callsign** are close enough (as in the case of the first two rows), we should choose the line with the smaller value of **AirportSize**

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are looking to accomplish? In the question you say "Callsign with the smallest value of AirportSize only if Distance between airports for the same Callsign is less than 1" which is done by calculating the difference in the `Distance` column. For `CES219 ` the difference between that row and the next is `3.685661` You also need to define "close enough"

Comment: I have 12 lines with 4 different **Callsing** values: HVN19, CCA839, CES219 and ETH704. My goal is to filter out these lines and have only 4 lines with smallest **Distance** based on 2 conditions. The first condition is to drop other lines within the same **Callsign** by calculating the difference of column **Distance**, taking into account the very first row of each **Callsign** .  In the example, If difference between line 6 compared to the lines 7 and 8 is more than 1, we can drop these lines (line 7 and line 8).

Comment: However, if we still have two lines after condition 1, we consider the next condition 2: AirportSize. Here, we just choose the line with the smallest value in ** AirportSize**, as it was explained in the question. I hope you got my point :)

Comment: Much better explanation. Another question . . . You said "taking into account the very first row of each Callsign" Is it always the first row or could you have a situation where the distance between the same `callsign` is something like `[1.5, 10, 10.2]` where the distance between the last two callsigns is .2 and therefore would be kept?

Comment: It should be always the very first row, it is not required to consider other lines within the same **callsign**. Even if the last two rows are pretty close to each other ``[1.5, 10, 10.2] ``, the overall goal is to have the smallest **distance**. So in this case, we can drop immediately these last two rows. Only if **distance** of the first and the second row are close to each other (<1), then we should apply condition 2, related to the column **AirportSize**

Comment: @uma I think my solution should meet your criteria. I had an answer up that I changed after you clarified some things in the comments

Comment: @ClayShwery thank you very much for your help! it works perfectly! :)

Comment: Can you also show what code you have written and why it doesn't perform as you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarified requirements in the comments, here is a working solution, that can be run and returns the expected result.

It should be very efficient as well.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df_txt = """
Id  Calls   Distance  AirportSize
0   HVN19   3.727263    2
1   HVN19   3.727263    1
2   HVN19   11.485452   2
3   CCA839  2.094717    2
4   CCA839  2.094717    1
5   CCA839  6.622537    2
6   CES219  1.751279    1
7   CES219  5.436940    4
8   CES219  6.950773    4
9   ETH704  2.976954    4
10  ETH704  3.844980    4
11  ETH704  5.452634    4
"""
    
df1 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(df_txt)).set_index('Id').rename(columns = {'Calls':'Callsign'})


# Need to sort or to ensure following will always work
df1.sort_values(['Callsign','Distance'])
# calc distance between each subsequent ap - fillna as 0 for closest ap
df1['dist_diff'] = df1.groupby('Callsign')['Distance'].diff().fillna(0)
df1['dist_diff'] = df1.groupby('Callsign')['dist_diff'].cumsum()

# Keep only smallest qualifiying airport for each callsign, tiebreak with Distance
df1[df1['dist_diff']<1].sort_values(['Callsign','AirportSize','Distance']).drop_duplicates('Callsign').drop('dist_diff',axis=1)
```

output

```
    Callsign    Distance    AirportSize
Id          
4   CCA839  2.094717    1
6   CES219  1.751279    1
9   ETH704  2.976954    4
1   HVN19   3.727263    1
```